# Laravel. The default route for the prefix does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7

For some reason, the default route does not work (just "/admin")

```
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@main')->name('index');
    Route::get('/main', 'AdminController@main')->name('main');
});
```

Route list:

```
  admin                      | admin.index            | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@main                              | web        |
```

Comment: what is the error it is showing admin in route list

Comment: not error, Just redirect to home

Comment: does not work don't tell anything you need to specify what you want what is the current scenario, what you are aiming for

Comment: My current scenario: when typing in the /admin address bar, navigate to the index function in the AdminController